# Configure WCF client endpoint to use a relative address (for Azure)

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, wcf-binding, basichttpbinding

I have a Windows Azure Cloud Service project containing **multiple Web Roles** to host some services. I want to use **ServiceX** in **ServiceY** (each running on **diffrent roles**) using an **relative** URL.

Thats the way I host ServiceX:

```
<service name="ServiceX">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceX" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```

Now I want to use that service in ServiceY. With an absolute URL it works fine:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="ServiceXProxy"
          address="http://mycloudservice.cloudapp.net:8080/ServiceX.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="ServiceX"/>
...
```

But how can I use the ServiceX in ServiceY with a relative address? Isn't that possible since they running on the same cloud service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use relative addresses programmatically, but you still need to know the base address (*or just use localhost:8080 as the base*) - it's not possible to use relative addresses via the `web.config` unless you build a custom configuration or leverage `AppSettings`.

```
// create bindings & endpoints
var baseAddress = System.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddress"];
var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(baseAddress + "/ServiceX.svc");
```

You could also load the client endpoint address from the `web.config` and override the base address using `UriBuilder` for similar means.